# Quitar espacios a una cadena en java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

me gustaría preguntarle algo

estoy haciendo un código que lee un archivo pasa que me toca leer comentarios a ver si están bien escritos el formato seria comentario de apertura (* y de cierre *)

**(*** Comentario ***)**

pero como estoy validando errores pienso en que pasaría si hicieran esto

(     20 espacios     *  comentario *)

entonces intento programar un código que a partir de **(** quite todos los espacios sean 20 o 40, con replaceAll("\\s"," ") yo puedo quitar todos los espacios y dejar solo 1 para analizar si existe o no * que sería la forma fácil.

pero replaceAll luego de ( no me quiere borrar todos los espacios y dejar unicamente 1 para analizar si existe * que sería la forma correcta del comentario.

este es mi codigo

```
            if (lineaSinEspacios.trim().contains("(") && lineaSinEspacios.contains(")")) {

                ComentarioUniLinea = lineaSinEspacios.replaceAll("\\s", " ");
                indiceComentarioApertura = lineaSinEspacios.indexOf("(");


            

            ComentarioUniLinea = ComentarioUniLinea.substring(indiceComentarioApertura);
            
            ComentarioUniLinea = ComentarioUniLinea.replaceAll("\\s", " ");

                if(ComentarioUniLinea.equals("*")){
                    System.out.println("Comentario Correcto");
                }
```

lo que pasa es que después de ( el código no me borra los espacio y deja 1 para analizar a ver si es * lo que existe o no, entonces nose que estaré haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es solo con la finalidad de leer puedes usar:

```
String entrada = "(hola*marca*)";
int a = entrada.indexOf("*");
String salida = entrada.substring( 0, 1 ) + entrada.substring( a, entrada.length() );
System.out.println( salida );

imprime -> (*marca*)
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias, si me sirvió